# How to clear HTML table after each use in a web DataGrid using VB.NET?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datagrid

I want to display the query result in the table using my code below.

My problem is that in the 2nd row of `DataGrid` the query result of 1st and 2nd row are displayed. Similarly in 3rd row 1st 2nd and 3rd row's results are displayed and so on.

Can someone tell me how to display query of only 2nd row in 2nd row of DataGrid and so on?

Is there any way to clear the table after a row get filled?

```
For Each d In DataGrid1.Items
   htbl = d.FindControl("Table1") 
   sql = "select username, count(*) as cnt from elexa where  r_id='" & d.Cells.Item(0).Text & "'  group by username order by cnt desc"
   cmd = New SqlCommand(sql, conn)
   adp=new SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
   adp.Fill(ds,"elexa")
   tbl = ds.Tables("elexa")
   tbl = ds.Tables("elexa")
   cnt = tbl.Rows.Count

   For i = 0 To cnt - 3

    Dim hRw As New HtmlTableRow
    Dim hRw2 As New HtmlTableRow

    For j = 0 To 2
      Dim hCll As New HtmlTableCell
      Dim hcll2 As New HtmlTableCell
      hCll.InnerHtml ="<font size=2>" & ds.Tables("elexa").Rows(i).Item("username") & "</font>"
      hRw.Controls.Add(hCll)
      i = i + 1
      hCll = New HtmlTableCell 
    Next j

 htbl.Controls.Add(hRw)
 hRw2.BgColor =  "silver"        
 hRw2.Height = "1px"

 Next

Next d
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the results of the previous selects stay in the dataset `ds`.
So you get one result for the first select, two for the second, three for the third and so on.

You could append the id to the table name `"elexa" + d.Cells.Item(0).Text` or create a new dataset for each request.

So you can just change

```vb
adp.Fill(ds,"elexa")
tbl = ds.Tables("elexa")
tbl = ds.Tables("elexa")
```

to

```vb
apd.Fill(ds, "elexa" + d.Cells.Item(0).Text)
tbl = ds.Tables("elexa" + d.Cells.Item(0).Text)
```

Like this, you create a new table for each row and don't have to clear it in some way.

Comment: we cant get the row count before the command querry because we are getting the cnt value fron data table, which we get after the querry gets executed, i thought of using a for loop for getting different dataset value..but as we dnt have cnt value is there is any other ways for doing it?

Comment: Well, didn't I? What about `"elexa" + d.Cells.Item(0).Text`?
OK, I will add a better example.
But as I can see, you just added my other suggestion (to create new datasets) as solution.

Answer (score 0):

I got the desired result by creating a new dataset after each row